# If calculated value column exceeds 24 hours

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, calculated-column, date-time

I got this calculated column that shows values of "hh:mm:ss". But i've noticed that if its exceeds 24:00:00 it will restarts to ex. 01:00:00..

Is there any way to make a validation or format the column so when it exceeds ex. 23:59:59 it will show the text "Over 24> hours" or something?

Or is there any way to make it exceed 24:00:00?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new calculated column named cal1 with the formula as :

```
=TEXT(DateAndTime,"hh")
```

Then edit your original calculated column with the formula as:

```
=IF(cal1="00","24:"&TEXT(DateAndTime,"mm:ss"),TEXT(DateAndTime,"hh:mm:ss"))
```

"DateAndTime" is a date column that you get date and time information. the formula means if the cal1 column return the hour as 00, replace it as 24.

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Looks promising! I Will test this tonight. Is there anyway to make it go up to even 48 hours? Do l just add "01","25:" and so on in the code?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But how did you define your original date column? How did you distinguish real first hour and 25th hour? If just change 01 with 25, it will not distinguish 01 hour and 25 hour.